# How do you stop text moving during Jquery animations?

Tags: jquery

Hi im trying to add some effects to divs on my website using Jquery. I want some elements to expand out on load and then when the user leaves the page I want the divs to close the opposite way the opened. My problem is that when the animations play (both opening and closing) the text seems to go on new lines whilst the box is getting smaller, how do I stop that from happening?

I can show you an example on this website 
See Example 3 (Collapse left) - Note the Moving Text

http://www.adipalaz.com/experiments/jquery/expand_collapse_different_directions.html

Comment: and how do you plan on forcing the user to wait for the animation when they close the webpage (or is it an animation for content transition within an AJAX site)?

Comment: Animate the _margins_ like example 5 and 6 instead of the _width_?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a way to achieve this. You need to have an `inner` and `outer` container for each object. You then move the `inner` container left or right and have the `outer` container's `overflow` property set to `hidden`.

[Check out this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/sbXYU/)

Comment: to 'slide' out to the right just change `left: "-200px"` to `left: "+200px"`